# text by right positioned iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I would like to make an index (iframe) of a page but I can not done in front of the text. The text comes behind iframe or iframe not on the right corner, no matter what I try.

page.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>


    <iframe src="index.html" height="520" style="right: 10px; position:fixed">
    </iframe>


some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text -- some text

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
            BODY {
            COLOR: #0080FF;
            BACKGROUND: black;
        -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

some text  </br>

some text  </br>

some text  </br>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to have text at the side of iframe not behind and iframe on the right side of the text floating when scrolling so it is always visible. ifame should not go up or down like the rest of the text on the page. Or is there any better way to do it, not with iframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with some simple floats. I would move your CSS styling [to an external file](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp). This is a barebones example for you to fill in the rest with whatever you want.

```css
// style.css

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.some-text {
  float: left;
  width: 250px; // change to whatever you like 
}
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px; // change to whatever you'd like 
}
```

```html
 

<!-- page.html --> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="some-text">

    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>Some text, some text, some text</p>

  </div>

  <iframe src="index.html" frameborder="0" />

</div>
```

Comment: How can I make a link in index.html  to jump to part of the page.html without loading the whole page.

Comment: Are you wanting to load the link in the iframe @andrej?

Comment: no, in page.html. I think I found it. I will add `target="_parent"` in index.html.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down and you will see that the iframe stays where it is.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/brf3zopv/1/)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.maintext {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 320px);
}
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  top:10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="maintext">

    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p><strong>Scroll and you will see that the iframe stays put.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt libero nec justo tempus, facilisis dictum leo pellentesque. Proin nulla est, dignissim ac nibh at, cursus imperdiet nisl. Sed cursus libero at varius viverra. Proin rutrum placerat dapibus. Mauris sed justo vestibulum, ultricies risus nec, ullamcorper erat. Pellentesque in gravida magna, nec feugiat dui. Proin urna nunc, mattis eu pellentesque ultricies, accumsan vel dui.

Donec faucibus sit amet neque vitae semper. Vivamus rhoncus egestas convallis. Morbi rutrum tellus et diam pharetra, nec vehicula lectus facilisis. Etiam blandit augue quis volutpat luctus. Etiam rhoncus sodales suscipit. Quisque pellentesque vitae arcu at ullamcorper. Vivamus lectus dui, varius vel enim ac, gravida molestie augue. Mauris sed tortor nisi.

Quisque id orci facilisis, faucibus metus et, ullamcorper tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus semper lacus egestas mauris sodales, et efficitur velit iaculis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus eleifend odio eget eleifend lobortis. Morbi et ante scelerisque erat sagittis dictum. Maecenas nec arcu id enim euismod sagittis. Sed consectetur porttitor sodales. Integer ac pretium risus. Cras vel tortor eros. Nunc ut orci ultricies, euismod ante sit amet, volutpat mauris. Fusce ultrices turpis ut luctus vulputate. Cras vitae hendrerit quam. Maecenas in augue varius, scelerisque sapien ut, suscipit neque.</p>

  </div>

  <iframe src="http://www.musicmatters.ie" frameborder="1" />

</div>
```

Comment: I think left and right are wrong in this answer. They should be switched.